# Probabilty of three tickets randomly drawn from $(2n + 1)$ tickets to be in $A.P.$

Tags: probability

Out of  $(2n + 1)$ tickets conseautively numbered from $1$ to $2n + 1$, three are drawn at random. Find the probability that the numbers on them are in $A.P.$

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: i am stuck at how to find the total number of three numbers to be in AP it is going to long an lengthy in my way and confusing to

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Establish a bijection between an AP with 3 terms, and pairs of integers with the same parity.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**: Let's say we draw two tickets: $a, b$. We have to draw a third ticket $c$. For $a, b, c$ to be in AP,

$$c = |a-b| + max(a, b)$$

Or,

$$c = min(a, b) - |a-b|$$

Therefore, there are only $2$ possible values for the third ticket for arbitrarily chosen $a$ and $b$.

EDIT:

Another possible value for $c$ is

$$c = \frac{a+b}{2}$$

But this will only work if $a$ and $b$ have the same parity.

Comment: What about $c=\dfrac{a+b}{2}$ ?

Comment: Yes, but that will only work if $a$ and $b$ have the same parity.